# How to get list of "most used apps" on Android

Tags: android

Android has a feature that allows you to sort your apps according to "most used first"

I am using the ACTION_SEND feature and I need to filter the messaging apps to send that message. I want to order the list of available messaging apps in decreasing order of daily usage - Is this order and list accessible on any class similar to PackageManager?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API within PackageManager or similar.

(Where in Android are you seeing a sort order of "most used first"?  It's easy enough for some launcher to keep a count of which apps are launched most through it, but the OS as a whole does not make "most used" information available).

Some apps have tried to keep track of this information by running a service that continually monitors what the current foreground app is - but when they see what this does to battery life they give up and decide they don't need to know that information!

Comment: You can see the "most used list" while sorting your apps on your dock. There are also other options like "sort by alphabetical order", "sort by recent app" etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "your dock"?  Are you using a stock Android (Nexus) device, or do you have some manufacturer provided alternative launcher that provides "most used" information that Android itself does not?